# Rails order query method for multiple and child attributes

Tags: ruby-on-rails

While the new rails syntax implements an [attribute that chooses the order direction as a symbol](https://api.rubyonrails.org/classes/ActiveRecord/QueryMethods.html#method-i-order) with colons,
I have not found a way to enact this syntaxic method for the following old-school style of ordering, when invoking multiple attributes where at least one is from a child table

```
@items = Item.eager_load(:itemoptions)
             .order('model_id ASC, itemoptions.modeloption_id ASC')
             .where( [...])
             .all
```

how can this be achieved with the new approach?

Comment: Why are you calling `all` at the end? What's your Rails version?

Comment: version rails 5.2.3

Answer (score 1, accepted):

As you're joining both tables, you need to prefix the columns you're using with their corresponding table names.

The only arguments for direction that `order` is able to receive are `[:asc, :desc, :ASC, :DESC, "asc", "desc", "ASC", "DESC"]`, so that forces you to pass the columns as hash keys in the form `{ "table_name.column_name" => <direction> }`.

Try with:

```
Item.eager_load(:itemoptions)
    .where( [...])
    .order('items.id' => :ASC, 'itemoptions.modeloption_id' => :ASC)
```

You don't need the `all` method there.

Comment: good clarification.  Well then, this is one instance where the new syntax does not save any characters...

Answer (score 0):

The error message that I receive says that it's possible to use Arel's sql escape to do this. Currently I am able to do something like `Item.eager_load(:itemoptions).order(Arel.sql("model_id ASC, itemoptions.modeloption_id ASC"))`

Also I know not part of the question, but I don't think you need the `.all` at the end

Comment: the shown line does work; no need to invoke `Arel` ; the question is, how to use the new colon-based syntax (question edited for expliciteness).  And, horizontal scroll to the end... `.all` was there

Comment: There is a need to invoke Arel in Rails 6 as they will discontinue raw sql being passed in unless escaped with Arel tho